# How to specify fields to set for accepts_nested_attributes_for in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes

I have something like:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user    
   delegate :full_name, :to => :user

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
   .......
```

This work fine as I want profile to be able to set first_name and last_name in user. But this poses security threat if user injects other parameters in the form.

How to make accepts_nested_attributes_for only takes first_name and last_name and drop other paramters?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that I can think of and they are actually the same way you would handle the mass assignment without going through anaf.

1. accepts_nested_attributes_for will respect attrs_accessible on the user model.  If you specify that an attribute is not exposed to mass assignment on the user model, it will not be able to be assigned through accepts_nested_attributes_for either.
2. You can handle the sanitation in your profiles controller.  Attributes that will be passed to the user model will come in under params[:profile][:user_attributes].  You can then either use `slice` to only get the attributes you want to allow, or use `except` to delete the attributes you don't want to allow.  Though I prefer to whitelist allowed attributes vs blacklisting.

Option 1 would affect anywhere you are using mass assignment for the user model, while option 2 would only affect parameters coming in through the profiles controller